# C++ SDL collision between sprites

Tags: c++, sdl, sprite, collision

After 30 minutes Googling, all I could find is this:
http://www.sdltutorials.com/sdl-collision

I thought the title was misleading, then I noticed it's just a nightmare of a way to detect collision between two sprites. All I want is to check whenever my player sprite touches something else (another sprite). How can I accomplish this?

I read there is a library called SDL_collision.h, but it's either in Pascal or empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are you'd use [`SDL_Rect`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Rect) for your bounding box. Where `x` and `y` are the positions of your sprite, and `w` and `h` are the width and height of your sprite. Then all you need to do is use [`SDL_HasIntersection`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_HasIntersection).

Here is a simple example:

```
SDL_Surface *Srfc1, *Srfc2;
Srfc1= IMG_Load("foo.png");
Srfc2= Srfc1;
Srfc2->refcount++;

SDL_Rect box1, box2;
box1.x = box1.y = 0;
box2.x = box2.y = 100;
box1.w = box2.w = Srfc1->w;
box2.h = box2.h = Srfc1->h;

// ... somewhere in your event handling logic
if (SDL_HasIntersection(&box1, &box2))
{
    printf("Collision.");
}
// ...

SDL_FreeSurface(Srfc1);
SDL_FreeSurface(Srfc2);
```

---

Since you do not have `SDL_HasIntersection`, here's a quick little function that will suit your needs:

```
    bool IntersectRect(const SDL_Rect * r1, const SDL_Rect * r2)
    {
  return !(r2->x > (r1->x + r1->w) || 
           (r2->x + r2->w) < r1->x || 
           r2->y > (r1->y + r1->h) ||
           (r2->y + r2->h) < r1->y);
            );
    }
```

For reference the logic is:

```
  return !(r2.left > r1.right || 
           r2.right < r1.left || 
           r2.top > r1.bottom ||
           r2.bottom < r1.top);
```

Where 'right' and 'bottom' refer to 'x + width' and 'y + height' respectively. Use this to fix the function incase I made a typo.

Comment: It would solve my problem if I didn't get an 'Error: Identifier "SDL_HasIntersection" is undefined'. What am I doing wrong now?

Comment: @Yop Try including `SDL_rect.h`

Comment: I tried including SDL_rect.h, but my IDE said the header didn't exist, so I googled it and put it with the other SDL headers. Then it said it required SDL_pixels.h which I didn't have either. I downloaded it and now I got a bunch of errors. Maybe SDL_HasIntersection comes in a different version of SDL or something? I don't think I'm getting this function the right way.

Comment: Now the game's doing weird things, but I'm guessing it's my fault. Now I can continue myself, thanks to this, thanks!